# How to add text to an existing shape(textbox) in C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an excel which contains textboxes/shapes which I am going to fill in with specific data. I used the following code in identifying each shape:

```
//using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet
foreach(Excel.Shape shp in xlworksheet.Shapes)
{
    //code to add text to shape goes here....
}
```

I also tried using:

```
shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Test";
```

and

```
shp.TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Text = "Test";
```

but gives an error which states `The specified value is out of range` and `Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))`, respectively.

What should be the correct approach in adding texts to existing textboxes?

Comment: Does your worksheet have only Text Box shapes?

Comment: @jhmt not all are text boxes. how will I read all shapes that are only text boxes? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can indentify the text box by its name. For example, if the name is "TextBox 1",  `xlworksheet.Shapes.Item("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Text = "Test";`

Comment: Do I have to assign names to each text box inside my excel file?

Comment: Now I understand the problem. I added my answer from the answer box and try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to check if the type of `Shape` is `msoTextBox` before setting text.

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet
foreach (Excel.Shape shp in xlworksheet.Shapes)
{
    if (shp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
    {
        shp.TextFrame.Characters(Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Text = "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks. ^_^